# I am getting null pointer exception uploading file using struts2

Tags: java, struts2

Here i am uploading file and I wanted to read file type and file extension but when I give file am getting nullpointer exception near FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploadFile, fileToCreate); could anybody plz solve this problem...

```
public class ImportAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private File uploadFile;
    private String uploadFileName;
    private String uploadContentType;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public File getUploadFile() {
        return uploadFile;
    }

    public void setUploadFile(File uploadFile) {
        this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
    }

    public String getUploadFileName() {
        return uploadFileName;
    }

    public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
        this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
    }

    public String getUploadContentType() {
        return uploadContentType;
    }

    public void setUploadContentType(String uploadContentType) {
        this.uploadContentType = uploadContentType;
    }
    RegisterDAO dao = new RegisterDAO();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * @throws
     * Exception
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.uploadFileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploadFile, fileToCreate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }
        Model m = new Model();
        String result = m.fileimport(uploadFile, uploadFileName);
        if (result.equals(SUCCESS)) {
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {
            addActionError(getText(result));
            return "failure";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("inside validate of LA");
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        this.servletRequest = hsr; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

This is my jsp page

```
<s:form method="post" action="file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <s:file label="choose file" name="uploadFile"></s:file>
            <s:submit></s:submit>
        </s:form>
```

i have print my file path its coming like this
filepathD:\ranjith\ranjithdemo3\build\web\

Comment: You have not initialized uploadFile and uploadFileName.. Or not shared that code alteast

Comment: could u plz tell me how to do that   thanks

Comment: where to initialize that one

Comment: You have declared this without any default value - private File uploadFile;.. Now if there is no value set to uploadFile via its setter setUploadFile, it will remain null. The setter should be called when you submit the request

Comment: but if i remove the filepatha for reading am gettting file

Comment: could anybody plz look my edit i have printed my file path it like filepathD:\ranjith\ranjithdemo3\build\web\

Comment: print uploadFile and uploadFileName and see what you get

Comment: am getting like this filepathD:\ranjith\ranjithdemo3\build\web\
fileD:\prabha\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\work\Catalina\localhost\ranjithdemo3\upload_7965713f_1420293e1db__7ff7_00000000.tmp
filenamenull

Comment: i am getting like this

Comment: filename am getting null...

Comment: so does it makes you clear? The filename is null

Comment: As its giveing me filename is null but I set properly by using setters and getters

Answer (score 1):

This is the third question with this code in less than 24 hours... is this taken by an online arcticle ? Could you report it here please?

BTW, the main problem is that in uploading file with Struts2, through fileUploadInterceptor, you must respect the following structure

```
private File   <filevarname>;
private String <filevarname>FileName;
private String <filevarname>ContentType;
```

so if your `<filevarname>` is "uploadFile", you should have

```
private File uploadFile;
private String uploadFileFileName;
private String uploadFileContentType;
```

if you change it to "upload" instead, it should be

```
private File upload;
private String uploadFileName;
private String uploadContentType;
```

that is more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

please check;

1. field name in html form with respect to ActionServlet
2. check enc-type with the html-form

Answer (score 0):

Check if renaming your content type field in your action class from `uploadContentType` to `uploadFileContentType` works. 
Also change the `uploadFileName`  to  `uploadFileFileName`.

Change corresponding getter and setter as well. I am not sure if it is causing the issue. So this is more sort of trial and error suggestion.

Update:
It seems you are getting the NPE on GET action.

Before your try block add this code:

```
if(!servletRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
   return INPUT;
}
```

This is not very elegant but should work for this example. I have checked it. :)

Comment: mu file path is coming like this filepathD:\ranjith\ranjithdemo3\build\web\

Comment: and filename - Is it non-null?

Comment: am creating filename filed and am adding setters and getters for that could u see my model above